# How to post object with Set/Array field in typescript/angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have class like:

```
export class LogModel {
..
componentSet: Set<string>;
constructor(componentSet: Set<string>) {
    this.componentSet = componentSet;
}
```

And I need to post this class to Spring boot app. But I have the problem with JSON deserialization because: 
[image]

And I have to use transform method like

```
`private toArray(set) {
        let array: string[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < set.length; ++i)
            array[i] = set[i];
        return array;
    }`
```

in order to have [image]
How to properly POST this class?

Comment: So you want to convert `Set` to `Array`? Is this exactly you want?

Comment: @ArpitMeena No. I use this method for: componentSet: []

Comment: accept the answer if you are satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this before sending to post method

```
const postValue = Array.from(this.componentSet);
```

(OR)

```
const setValues = this.componentSet.values();
const postValue = Array.from(setValues);
```

Then post the `postValue`

Comment: Array.from(this.componentSet) is sufficient.